# Update my mongodb schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema, mongoose

Currently, my schema for my mongodb app is very straightforward. However, I'd like to simplify and clean it up further. What's the best way of updating my schema design? Should I just write a remapper in my language of choice using a library (fairly trivial), or is there a simpler way?

I don't mind doing the above, I just would like to know if there's a really obvious way of doing it reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to migrate your schema, mongodb like any NoSQl system is an answer to schema problems of RDBMS.

That said, you will have to migrate your data by making a migration script.

You might find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617002/dealing-with-schema-changes-in-mongoose) useful.

Comment: I guess I'd rather migrate the data rather than the schema. Thanks for the answer, I'll write a migration script.