# mongoose populate field without ref option

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 schema:

```
var User1Schema = new Schema({
    name: {type:String , trim: true, required: true },
    status: {type:Number, required: true, default:1}
},{collection:"user_1"});
```

,

```
var User2Schema = new Schema({
    name: {type:String , trim: true, required: true },
    email: {type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true} },
    status: {type:Number, required: true, default:1}
},{collection:"user_2"});
```

and

```
var ConversationSchema = new Schema( {

    participants: [{user:{type: ObjectId, required: true}],
    creator: {type: ObjectId, required: true},

    status: { type:Number, required: true, default:1 }

}, { collection:"conversation" } );
```

In ConversationSchema I have creator field whic has now ref option, because it can be type of User1Schema or User2Schema.

How can I populate creator field using mongoose

Comment: See the `mongoose-dbref` plugin: https://github.com/goulash1971/mongoose-dbref

Comment: Here's a more up-to-date branch of `mongoose-dbref` https://github.com/apiaryio/mongoose-dbref.  However, if at all possible, you should try to just change your schema instead of branching it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617002/dealing-with-schema-changes-in-mongoose

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
Conversation.find().populate('creator', null, 'User2').exec(callback)
```

The [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) aren't clear. Will update soon.

Also, the syntax for this will be simpler in v3.6.

Comment: This allows for a multiple-reference field, I imagine?  e.g., a `_author` of a document might be a `User` ObjectId _or_ it might be an `Organization` ObjectId?

Comment: yep, if you know which model is necessary you can specify this at query time.

Comment: Does this also work for a Mixed type field where the path refers to an ObjectId?

Comment: @KevinWang It appears to!. Just make sure the 3rd parameter of the populate call is a string with the same name as the mongoose Model you're trying to populate.

Comment: What if I want to populate creator in multiple models e.g 'User1' and 'User2'? I see only the last specified model is populated and all the previous models return null.

Comment: can we save the model name in the  ConversationSchema as a field and then pass it to populate ?

Comment: @aaronheckmann do u have answer of anoopsingh/dantheta question?

Answer (score 1):

As of 27th March 2019 the way to do so is:

1) Setting the field you want to populate as a ObjectId **without** providing a ref.

```
var eventSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  // The id of the corresponding conversation
  // Notice there's no ref here!
  conversation: ObjectId
});
```

2) While making the query pass the model for the schema along with the query:

```
Event.
  find().
  populate({ path: 'conversation', model: Conversation }).
  exec(function(error, docs) { /* ... */ });
```

REF: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#cross-db-populate