# mongoose populate generic array of ObjectId without ref

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I'm using mongoose 4.6.6, express 4.13, passport 0.3.

I have the next mongoose Schema

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  nombre: String,
  apellidos: String,
  email: String,
  pass: String,
  fecha_registro : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  rol_list: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], // generic array of objectId
  deleted: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

When I search a user and try to populate the "rol_list" array, is always empty.
I have looked in mongo the users are well filled, but mongoose return it empty.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id)
    .populate('rol_list')
    .exec(function(err, user) {
      console.log(user);
      done(err, user);
    });
});
```

The console.log(user) show always the array rol_list empty.

If I assign a reference to the ObjectId like:

```
rol_list: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Rol1' }]
```

than is correct filled, logically only with the element "Rol1".

Any idea?

Comment: What is the name of the schema behind `rol_list`?

Comment: no, no have schema behind. I want a generic array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in `.populate(...)` mongoose function that allow you to specify the model that's behind the `ObjectId`.

**@example**

```
Conversation.find().populate('creator', null, 'User2').exec(callback);
```

---

[Stack overflow post: mongoose-populate-field-without-ref-option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627948/mongoose-populate-field-without-ref-option)

Answer (score -1):

If you want array of only object ids then don't use populate with it.

like:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id)
    .exec(function(err, user) {
      console.log(user);
      done(err, user);
    });
});
```