# mongoDB schema changes results in error for old users?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a schema in my server like this:

```
deliveryAddress :  {
        city: String,
        state: String,
        country: String,
        zipcode: String
      }
```

but because of future enhancement we were required to add phone number to this `deliveryAddress` collection object. but the user who are already registered will face the problem how do i solve this.

The schema should look like this in future:

```
deliveryAddress :  {
        city: String,
        state: String,
        country: String,
        zipcode: String,
        phoneNumber:String
      }
```

Comment: You can add a default, value, and when he will be fetched if the value does not exists mongoose will provide the default value

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru i think you have not understood the problem. my production is working with the first example deliveryAddress if i add the one which is at 2nd example to production.the users who are registered with the 1st example collection will have problem(if in case i tried to query with phoneNumber)

Comment: You can version the deliveryAddress. For instance, add a field called version: number. Then for version not set/zero not require phoneNumber and for version 1 require address. That way existing users are not forced to provide one.