# update schema in mongoose to add new property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to update a schema to add a new property field.  I was hoping it would be as simple as adding the property to the schema with the updated field being accessible.

I have an existing schema

```
  let userDrinkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  new Schema
    creator : { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'user'  // name of user file
    },
    caffeine: Number,
    mgFloz: Number,
    name: String,
    size: Number,
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});
```

I need to add the id from this schema

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I am not sure how to add this property for each user.  I followed this example   [Dealing with schema changes in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617002/dealing-with-schema-changes-in-mongoose)

The schema is now:

```
let DrinkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'user',
        required: true,
        default: null
    },
    caffeine: Number,
    mgFloz: Number,
    name: String,
    size: Number,
    imageUrl: String,
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
},
{
    collection: 'drinkList'
});
```

Unfortunately for me the user is null as well

```
{
 "_id":"58bba13bb7afeaa3180aa929",
 "caffeine":422,"mgFloz":218.7,
 "name":"10 Hour Energy Shot",
 "size":1.93,
 "url":"/caffeine-content/10-hour-eternal-shot",
 "date":"2017-03-28T13:10:12.650Z",
 "user":null
}
```

Is there a way to update the user field to get the user information?  The schema that I am referencing is set up as

```
const SelectedDrinks = require('./userDrinks').schema;
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    caffeine_list: [SelectedDrinks]
})
```

I can see that mongodb adds an id to each user when they are created.  this is what i am trying to access.

My backend route is configured in express.  With postman I can get this to work becuase I have the **user id**.  I am not sure how to get the correct user id inside of this route.

```
    router.post('/addDrink', (req, res, next) => {
    let newDrink = new UserDrinks({
        creator: req.body.creator, // need id get user object id()
        caffeine: req.body.caffeine,
        mgFloz: req.body.mgFloz,
        name: req.body.name,
        size: req.body.size,
        updated_at: req.body.updated_at
    });

    newDrink.save( (err) => {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            User.findOne({ _id: newDrink.creator},  (err, user) => {
                user.caffeine_list.addToSet(newDrink)
                user.save( function (err) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }else {
                        res.status(201).json(newDrink);
                    }
                })
            })

        }

    })
});
```

Comment: Did you update the `drinkList` collection with the new data?

Comment: @chridam Essentially, I need to define the property in the collection first?  like db.drinklist.update({}, {$set : {"user":" not sure here"}})?

Comment: You need to update the document with the corresponding user's `ObjectId` value, I don't know the relationship

Comment: @chridam That is what I thought I was doing in user, but clearly not.  I am updating my question to show the other collections.

Comment: Are you looking to rename your field from `creator` to `user` in `drinklist` collection ? Something like `db.drinklist.updateMany( {}, { $rename: { "creator": "user" } } )` ?? You can then access the `user` with the new schema.

Comment: I didn't think of that.  Would it be best to set up the update in the route controller?  I do not want to manually do this in the shell.

Comment: You can expose it over route and pass the query, but this is one time thing right ? Something like `DrinkModel.update(
  { },
  { $rename: { creator: 'user' } },
  { multi: true },
  function(err, data) { console.log(err, data); }
);`

Comment: If I expose it in a route it would just update the current user so it wouldn't be.  I think a better approach would be to do the update over all of the user and work from there.

Comment: yeah I think you should just use shell and rename it but if you really wanted to use mongoose then you should expose a separate route for just this part as you have already noted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right, you're trying to replace the `creator` field with the `user` field.  To accomplish this you'll need to do 2 things:

1. Modify your `/addDrink` route
2. Update any existing documents in the `drinkList` collection

**1) When you create `newDrink`, set `user` instead of `creator`:**

```
let newDrink = new UserDrinks({
    user: req.body.creator,
    caffeine: req.body.caffeine,
    mgFloz: req.body.mgFloz,
    name: req.body.name,
    size: req.body.size,
    updated_at: req.body.updated_at
});
```

**2)  Update all `UserDrinks` to rename the field:**

```
UserDrinks.update({}, { $rename: { "creator" : "user" } }, { multi: true }, callback)
```

This will find all UserDrinks documents and rename the `creator` property to `user`.

A quick way to do this without having to create a new route for a one-time change is to create a temporary function for it under your express setup, run it locally, and delete/comment the code after so it doesn't run again.  Ex:

```
function renameCreatorField() {
    UserDrinks.update({}, { $rename: { "creator" : "user" } }, { multi: true }, function(err, data) {
        if (!err) { 
            //success 
        }
    })
}

renameCreatorField();
```

This will run immediately when your server starts up.  Once it runs once you can delete it because the changes we made in (1) will ensure any future UserDrinks documents have the correct field set.

Of course, if you're just looking for a quick fix and this isn't a live application you can just do (1), clear out your database, and start fresh with correct documents.  But that's not the way to learn. :)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the response.  I had followed @Veeram and made updates in my mongo shell but the renameCreator function would have done the same.  Stuck on req.body.creator is still null for me which is causing my error.  Once I get this correct I am good to go.

Comment: What does your request body look like?  Both when you send it and when you print it out on your server.