# How to update mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

just started learning mongodb, currently i have this schema

```
var BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
image: String,
body: String,
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}});
```

and i wanted to update it to be like this, but currently its not working right now, when i checked it on the mongo console the schema is still the old one

```
var BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        title: String,
        image: String,
        body: String,
        created: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        author: {
            id: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "User"
            },
            username: String
        }
    });
```

this is the best i've come up with after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617002/dealing-with-schema-changes-in-mongoose%22this%22) post, but it throw me an error `TypeError: Undefined type undefined at author.required Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.`

```
var BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    body: String,
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: {
           type: String,
           required: true, 
           default: null
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Schema like that instead just make another `authorSchema` and use it as array.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var authorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
})

var BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    body: String,
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    author: [authorSchema]
})
```