# How to make a mongoose schema attribute unique after the schema is instantiated (already contains data)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, unique

I have a mongoose schema,

```js
const loggerSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        // Other ...
        cluster: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        // ...
    }
)
```

It currently filled with lots of data. I want to modify the `cluster` property to be as follows

```js
const loggerSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        // Other ...
        cluster: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique:true
        },
        // ...
    }
)
```

How do I achieve this without losing any of my data (in DB)? Provided that all existing data contain unique values on `cluster` attribute.

Comment: maybe dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617002/dealing-with-schema-changes-in-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there are no duplicate values of `cluster` you can change your schema immediately as you mentioned (if there are dups it will fail to create the unique index on `cluster`).
Read more about unique option [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).